# PHP - Translating cURL to PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, curl, geoserver, datastore

I am trying to upload PostGIS table from Postgres to GeoServer using php. However I am having issue translating cURL to its equivalent PHP.

> I am getting Http code: 405

cURL:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X PUT-H "Content-type: text/xml" -T pgstores.xml \
http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testworkspace/datastores.xml
```

PHP:

```
$url = "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testworkspace/datastores.xml";
                $headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'Accept: text/xml');
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, GEOSERVER_USER);

                $path = getcwd()."/uploads/pgstores.xml";
                $fp = fopen($path, "r");

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($path));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 405 is `method not allowed` so it seems your PHP is not using PUT

Comment: Internet research showed the same. What might be the solution to this issue? Any idea? Just getting started with cURL.